# How can i serve my website from binary files with litespeed web server enterpriese

Tags: deployment, ubuntu-22.04, litespeed, cyber-panel

i have a server with cyberpanel and ubuntu 22 and litespeed web server enterprise. I've made all configurations about dns, nameserver, domain etc and if i put an index.html file in "/home/(my-website-address).com/public_html" folder it serves it, even if i write the name of other files on later than actual url, for example `www.website.com/filename` it downloads that files to pc.

But i have a website in binary file and i want to serve my website via that binary file(which i tested on my ubuntu subsystem and compiled it on that machine and it works fine), so how can i serve that website when that domain have visited? My website also runs on `(server ip):4000`.

Comment: The binary file should be downloaded by default, if you want to serve it, please check the Server Configuration > General >  MIME Settings and add your custom Suffxies and MIME Type from there. If this binary runs as a web server, then you might want to set a reverse proxy to it.